# Postgres SQL - "my_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql:

```
select my_id, count(*) as total_count 
from (select col1, col2 from tableA
      union
      select col1, col2 from tableB
) as BothTable 
order by my_id
```

and getting this error `column "BothTable.my_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

How can I fix this problem here.

Comment: Your are missing a `from`.

Comment: that was a typo, now fixed in the question.

Comment: the error message is quite clear, you are missing a `GROUP BY my_id` before the `ORDER BY `

Comment: why do I need that?

Comment: Ok so col1, col2 are the columns in the bothTable.  except col1 and col2 are not my_ID so two issues 1) my_ID doesn't exist in BothTable.  2) when using aggregation, you must group by all the non-aggregated columns, or the engine will not know what value to return for the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: http://rextester.com/CSOY94991 for example on how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNT(*) will aggregate all of your rows together and so you won't be able to get a `my_id`.

If you `GROUP BY my_id` the resulting table will have 1 row for each `my_id` with a count of the number of unique rows that have the same value.

I.e.

```
my_id, COUNT(*)
<?>, 20
```

vs

```
my_id, COUNT(*)
1, 1
2, 10
3, 3
4, 1
5, 5
```

If you really just want the total count `SELECT count(*)` instead of `SELECT my_id, count(*)`

Comment: even without the `ORDER BY`, the query as written by the op won't work

Comment: why did it pick my_ID 5 in the first query?  is it random?

Comment: It will take the value from the last row accessed by the aggregation function.

Comment: You are confusing mysql with Postgresql. In the latter, the query won't run

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that point. I'll remove the point about ORDER BY then from my answer.

Comment: @Lamak Is that error because of postgres internals (is that aggregator run as a map?) or is it just a syntactic thing?